# Has TWRP been replaced by another custom recovery image?

Tags: twrp

There are two seemingly identical TWRP websites:

- http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/
- https://twrp.me/

twrp.me used the be TWRP's homepage. Their [Github](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project) page now points to http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/ and a new repository has been created to https://github.com/omnirom/android_bootable_recovery/

Comment: If the answer gets deleted: "both twrp.me and teamw.in resolve to 198.27.116.169".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, TWRP has not been replaced by another project, the issue you see is references to naming conventions that resolve to the same actual website, different name, same project. The websites are one and the same... Both twrp.me and teamw.in resolve to 198.27.116.169, which is the website host for TeamWin, the development team of TWRP.

Comment: I forgot IP check. You could have posted a comment instead, though.

Comment: @user598527 Why would I delete the answer or make it a comment instead? It is a valid and correct answer to your question, you could accept the answer and as well.

Comment: I asked if TWRP has been replaced by another project. You solved the issue I had with websites, I can't accept the answer because my question is left answered.

Comment: @user598527 Refined answer to more specifically address your question.

Comment: I still don't understand what is https://github.com/omnirom/android_bootable_recovery/ and from TWRP's Github page: "this is not up to date", please see [the same Github link]

Comment: TWRP's "base" code has always OmniROM, looks like after Android 6.0 the started using their Github too, it's the same project and people, if you want to know why specifically this was done, you would have to contact a Ethan Yonkers (DeesTroy) or one of there team at https://plus.google.com/communities/106804207647688456928 or the official XDA TWRP page at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1943625 Also note that what you reference in your question as "their Github page" isn't listed anywhere as their current Github page, the OmniROM Github is.